# Could Black Hole be formed with the center of some stars?

Tags: black-holes, astrophysics, estimation, stars, large-hadron-collider

If the LHC might make black holes, why would tiny or not so tiny black holes be potentially created with the very hot and dense core of a really big star?

Comment: Are you asking why small black holes aren't created inside stars? If so it's because the energy density there is much, much smaller than the density created at the collision point in the LHC.

Comment: @JohnRennie: That is surprising, that humans can create conditions that are more extreme than in the center of stars. When the Tsar Bomba went off I think I read that it either produced 1% of the energy the Earth receives from Sol or 1% of Sol's total output. Either way, impressive and I read further that this scared those in charge and they never did it again. and it was1% of sun's output: https://www.cs.mcgill.ca/~rwest/wikispeedia/wpcd/wp/t/Tsar_Bomba.htm#:~:text=This%20is%20equivalent%20to%20approximately,throughout%20the%20history%20of%20humanity.

Comment: See [Why is 7 TeV considered as a big amount of energy?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/229480/)

Answer (score 0):

The temperature in the core of the stars is not high enough for individual protons to reach the TeV energies of the LHC.

[1 GeV is equivalent to](http://www.saha.ac.in/theory/palashbaran.pal/conv.html) $1.16x 10^{13}$ K

[The hottest stars](https://spaceplace.nasa.gov/review/dr-marc-space/stars.html#hot) are of order of at most 50.000 K . It will be *very very* improbable that the tail of the distribution would have enough protons to hit enough other protons to reproduce the LHC energies.